# Задать значение в многомерном ассоциативном массиве PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Есть переменная `$target_val = "some"`, в которую нужно присвоить элементу в многомерном массиве,
к примеру такой

`$addresses = array('addresse'=>array('addr1'=>"",'addr2' =>""))`

и есть массив из набора ключей, в котором "путь" к нужному элементу

`$keys = ['addresse','addr1']`

Как при помощи массива типа $keys присвоить нужному элементу значение $target_val, что бы в результате было `$addresses = array('addresse'=>array('addr1'=>"some",'addr2' =>""))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все подобные вопросы, коих тут множество, будут сводиться к использованию цикла и ссылки на элемент массива.
что-то вроде такого

```
$data = [...];
$keys = [...];

$item = &$data;
foreach($keys as $k){
   $item = &$item[$k];
}
$item = "234";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$addresses[$keys[0]][$keys[1]] = $target_val;
```

Comment: Можно написать более поддерживаемый и расширяемый код, но в условии про это не сказано. А вообще, можно использовать рекурсию (обход дерева с агрегацией) и идти во всю глубину с помощью ключей из $keys, если использовали все или в массиве ничего не осталось (зависит от того, как будете отслеживать использованные ключи), то вы нашли в дереве свой целевой элемент и можете смело присваивать ему значение.